# Run for loop across multiple cells in ipynb

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter notebook which runs a script in R (not python unfortunately).

In one of the cells of the notebook, I assign a text to variable (e.g. iso <- 'USA'). I'd like to change this, so that this cell is a list of text strings (e.g. iso <- c('USA', 'Canada'...)). Then, I'd like to run every subsequent cell for every item on the list.

How can I do this? Its basically a for loop that runs across multiple cells in the notebook.

Help!

Comment: From the outset of your post, it's hard to follow what is going on without more details. "Jupyter notebook which runs a script in R" - this would mean you are running an R script from inside a notebook. Although that is common, the rest of your post indicates you are running R code in a notebook. Maybe eventually there's a script but cannot tell from limited information you supplied. "basically a for loop that runs across multiple cells in the notebook." - This isn't how notebooks work. You may want to review the REPL concept and Jupyter notebooks. Reorganizing your code/notebook would seem...

Comment: (continuing) in order. You can run a notebook inside another and parameterize notebooks when using Python. I'm not sure the routes for using R code that way though. However, the most direct way would be to modularize the lines of code you want to run into a function or an actual separate script file, and then iterate on your list of text strings in `iso` using that code.